# How can I tell if a certain key was pressed in Python?

Tags: python

```
import sys

print (sys.platform)
print (2 ** 100)
input('press Enter to exit')
```

Suppose I wanted to use the number 1 as the button that must be pressed to exit. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do what you want:

```
while(raw_input('Press "1" to exit.') != '1'):
    pass
```

Comment: But you need to enter and extra "Enter", since input is line buffered. Even if the question is not very clear, I assumed he wants to read a single keystroke, so I suggested the link below...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/1999-October/014262.html

Not so clean, but doable.

Comment: Gone.  Use this: http://web.archive.org/web/20080104144812/http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/1999-October/014262.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're building a command line app, why not use one of the libraries that help you build one.

For example:

- [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html)
- [urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/).